# Question about density in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ a topological space where $\tau=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}^2\}\cup \{D_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that $D_k=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,x+y<k\}$

I have to prove that $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2; ax+by+c=0, a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, a\neq b\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e., $\overline{A}=\mathbb{R}^2$

I know that we have $\overline{A}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ but i don't know how to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2\subset \overline{A}$

If i take $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $(x,y)\in\overline{A}$ iff $~\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_{(x,y)}, V\cap A\neq \emptyset $

but how is defined the neighborhood $V$ of $(x,y)$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Draw some pictures. Here’s a picture of a typical set $D_k$: it’s everything below the line $x+y=k$.

[image]

The set $A$ is just the line $ax+by+c=0$. If $a\ne b$, the slope of this line is not $-1$, so it’s not parallel to the boundaries of the sets $D_k$. Thus, $A$ intersects every line of the form $x+y=k$. That in turn means that for each $k\in\Bbb R$ there are points on the line $ax+by+c=0$ (i.e., points of $A$) that are below the line $x+y=k$ and hence are in the set $D_k$.

Comment: I like this solutions, but I find Hagen's solution really not helpful...

Comment: @FromCuba: You may not realize what it gives you. Pick a number less than $k$, say $k-1$, and plan on choosing $x$ and $y$ so that $x+y=k-1$. Then $$ax+by+c=a(x+y)+(b-a)y+c=a(k+1)+(b-a)y+c\;,$$ and since $b-a\ne 0$, you can solve for a value of $y$ that makes the expression $0$. Then let $x=(k-1)-y$, and you have a point in $A\cap D_k$. (I prefer not to leave this up too long, so I’ll delete it shortly.)

Comment: Please don't delete it Sir. This is helpful. I love the way you communicate maths. Maybe Hagen's solution is just too terse, or too dark, but you are a light in such darkness. THANKS!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you for your answer please have you an idea about how to prove that $B=\{D_k,k\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a basis for $\tau$ ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $(x,y)\in G\in \tau$, WLOG, we can assume $G\neq \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $(x,y)\in G=D_k$ for some $k$, that is $d=x+y<k$

Hence consider $l=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x+y-d=0\}\subset D_k$, note $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2; ax+by+c=0, a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, a\neq b\}$ is a line. Since $a\neq b$, $A$'s slope is different from $-1$. So $A$ and $l$ is not parallel, hence they must intersect at some point $P$.

So
$P\in l\cap A\subset D_k\cap A\neq \emptyset $ We have done.

Comment: $a\neq b$ so why $D_k\cap A\neq \emptyset $ ? please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Note given $a,b,c$,$A$ is a fixed line. Given $D_k$, we aim to show $D_k \capA$ is not empty. What we do is construct a line $l$ which is contained in $D_k$, and prove $l$ intersects $A$ is non-empty. Since $l$ has slope -1, $A$ has slope different from $-1 (a\neq b)$, so the two lines must intersect.

Comment: May I know what is the reason for a downvote?

Comment: @JohnZHANG: I'm rather curious about that myself, but experience suggests that an answer is unlikely to be forthcoming. I've upvoted both your answer and Hagen's elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to show that any nonempty open subset intersects $A$. Since $ax+by+c=a(x+y)+(b-a)y+c$, it is not hard to find $x,y$ such that $x+y<k$ and yet $ax+by+c=0$.

Comment: I dont understand your methods !